# pandas join gives NaN values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, join

I want to join 2 DataFrames

*Zipcode Database* (first 10 entries)

```
    0   zip_code           City       State       County  Population
0   0      90001    Los Angeles  California  Los Angeles       54481
1   1      90002    Los Angeles  California  Los Angeles       44584
2   2      90003    Los Angeles  California  Los Angeles       58187
3   3      90004    Los Angeles  California  Los Angeles       67850
4   4      90005    Los Angeles  California  Los Angeles       43014
5   5      90006    Los Angeles  California  Los Angeles       62765
6   6      90007    Los Angeles  California  Los Angeles       45021
7   7      90008    Los Angeles  California  Los Angeles       30840
8   8      90009    Los Angeles  California  Los Angeles           -
9   9      90010    Los Angeles  California  Los Angeles        1943
```

And *data* (first 10 entries)

```
    buyer                               zip_code
0   SWEENEY,THOMAS R & MICHELLE H       NaN
1   DOUGHERTY,HERBERT III & JENNIFER M  NaN
2   WEST COAST RLTY SVCS INC            NaN
3   LOVE,JULIE M                        NaN
4   SAHAR,DAVID NaN
5   SILBERSTERN,BRADLEY E TRUST         91199
6   LEE,SUSAN & JIMMY C                 92025
7   FRAZZANO REAL ESTATE I NC           NaN
8   RUV INVESTMENTS LLC                 91730
9   KAOS KAPITAL LLC                    NaN
```

So the final table should have [buyer, zip_code, City, County]. I'm joining with respect to Zip code.

```
data_2 = data.join(zipcode_database[['City', 'County', 'zip_code']].set_index('zip_code'), on='zip_code')
```

But the *city* and *county* columns are *NaN* even for the tuples in *data* where zipcode is actually present.

```
    buyer   zip_code    City    County
10  LANDON AVE TRUST 37736  NaN NaN NaN
11  UMAR,AHMAD  NaN NaN NaN
12  3 JPS INC   90717   NaN NaN
13  T & L HOLDINGS INC  95610   NaN NaN
14  CAHP HOLDINGS LLC   90808   NaN NaN
15  REBUILDING TOGETHER LONG BEACH  92344   NaN NaN
16  COLFIN AI-CA 4 LLC  NaN NaN NaN
17  GUTIERREZ,HUGO  91381   NaN NaN
18  VALBRIDGE CAP GOLDEN GATE FUND  NaN NaN NaN
19  SOLARES,OSCAR   92570   NaN NaN
```

Why is this the case? The zipcode database has all zipcodes from 90001 - 999950.

My first thought is the datatype of "zip_code" in both are different:

```
print(zipcode_database['zip_code'].dtype)
print(data['zip_code'].dtype)
```

Output:

```
int64
object
```

Thought of typecasting with `astype`, but this does not work with `NaN` values. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

You can cast `NaN` values to float types, but not int. In your case I would cast the `zip_code` field in both DataFrames to a float and then join.

```
zipcode_database.zip_code = zipcode_database.zip_code.astype(float)
data.zip_code = data.zip_code.astype(float)
data_2 = data.join(zipcode_database[['City', 'County', 'zip_code']].set_index('zip_code'), on='zip_code')
```

I can't reproduce anything meaningful from your example data (no matching zip codes), but that should fix the issue.